# Script to double quotes

Tags: windows, bash, key-bindings

I have a keyboard that does not have double quotes, when I need to use it, it's very difficult to remember the FN. How can I create a script so that when I press LShift + Escape it puts a double quote?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Can you also Accept my answer?

Comment: I'm assuming you want the changes to apply for all programs and not just input received by your bash shells. Could you edit your question to be clear on that? If you only care about input received by bash, look into [Readline key bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html). I don't think `shift+esc` can be mapped from though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create macros like this within bash. You would have to remap keyboard presses at the OS/application level.

If you're using a Mac, try [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/). If you're on a PC, try [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:windows].